# LCD displaying garbage on startup

Tags: python, spi, lcd, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm using a Raspberry Pi Zero wired to an Adafruit 1.14" 240 x 135 LCD (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-1-14-240x135-color-tft-breakout?view=all) with a python application configured to run on startup. My problem is the LCD screen shows garbage data on startup, before diving into the application.

Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFkfx.jpg

Using *sleep* statements, I found in my code the lines that trigger it:

```
disp = st7789.ST7789(spi, rotation=90, width=135, height=240, x_offset=53, y_offset=40, # 1.14" ST7789
    cs=cs_pin,
    dc=dc_pin,
    rst=reset_pin,
    baudrate=BAUDRATE,
)
```

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: It’s the creation/initialisation of the lcd driver - the display will be blank before this line. You need to make sure the parameters are correct for *your* lcd and the way you want to orient it.

Comment: The next thing your code should do is blank the display.

Comment: If it runs Linux, use in-kernel driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_RGB_Display/issues/84

My solution was to turn off the backlight and enable it after initializing and blanking the display. It seemed simpler than digging down to the driver code.